# Increment counter for each Grid View using the parameters (Flutter)

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a widget with the parameters to create the grid that I want to like the name or the gradient that I want, I added a new parameter to send a variable to increments it when I press a button or decrease it. There is a problem the increment is not working when I call it and stuck one number higher and one lower, but it works if I change the 'counter' in the widget not the parameter but the onPressed to any of the variables below, but the counter in all the grid view will change to one variable.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVMpT.jpg "Screenshot"

Here is the code: 
this is the variables

```
 int thoub = 0,
  shirt = 0,
  longPants = 0,
  shortPants = 0,
  shumgnGutr = 0,
  socks = 0,
  bsht = 0,
  tShirt = 0,
  miltUniform = 0,
  pakisUniform = 0,
  singleBlankets = 0,
  doubleBlankets = 0,
  abbya = 0;
```

here is when I call the widget:

```
myGridItems(
        'ثياب', //Arabic
        Colors.deepPurple.withOpacity(0.2),
        Colors.grey[300].withOpacity(0.35),
        thoub,
      ),
myGridItems(
        'فنايل', //Arabic
        Colors.deepPurple.withOpacity(0.2),
        Colors.grey[300].withOpacity(0.35),
        shirt,
      ),
```

and this is the widget itself:

```
Widget myGridItems(String gridName, Color color1, Color color2, int counter) {
return Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
      color1,
      color2,
    ], begin: Alignment.topLeft, end: new Alignment(1.0, 1.0)),
  ),
  child: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Opacity(
        opacity: 0.3,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(),
        ),
      ),
      Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if (counter != 50) counter++;
                    debugPrint('$counter');
                    print('add on pressed');
                  });
                },
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                  color: Colors.green,
                  size: 17.0,
                ),
              ),
              Text('$counter',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.blueGrey)),
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if (counter != 0) counter--;
                    debugPrint('$counter');
                    print('minus on pressed');
                  });
                },
                child: Icon(
                  const IconData(0xe15b, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),
                  color: Colors.red,
                  size: 17.0,
                ),
              ),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding:
                          const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 10.0, 15.0, 0.0),
                      child: Text(
                        gridName,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black54,
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      )
    ],
  ),
);
  }
```

this is the terminal

```
I/flutter (17441): 1
I/flutter (17441): add on pressed
I/flutter (17441): 0
I/flutter (17441): minus on pressed
I/flutter (17441): 1
I/flutter (17441): add on pressed
I/flutter (17441): 1
I/flutter (17441): add on pressed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your above question you are not able to update item count.I have added a global variable here to increase and decrease item count.

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Items extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _ItemsState();
  }
}

class _ItemsState extends State<Items> {
  int thoub = 1;
  int counterMain = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: thoub,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return myListItems('ثياب', //Arabic
      Colors.deepPurple.withOpacity(0.2),
      Colors.grey[300].withOpacity(0.35),
      counterMain,);
    });
  }


  Widget myListItems(String gridName, Color color1, Color color2, int counter) {

    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
          color1,
          color2,
        ], begin: Alignment.topLeft, end: new Alignment(1.0, 1.0)),
      ),
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Opacity(
            opacity: 0.3,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(),
            ),
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(

                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {

                        if (counter <50)
                          {
                            counterMain = counter+1;

                          }else{
                          debugPrint('in add else');

                        }
                        debugPrint('$counterMain');
                        print('add on pressed');
                      });
                    },
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.add,
                      color: Colors.green,
                      size: 17.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text('$counterMain',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.blueGrey)),
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        if (counter > 0) {
                          counterMain= counter-1;
                        }
                        debugPrint('$counterMain');
                        print('minus on pressed');
                      });
                    },
                    child: Icon(
                      const IconData(0xe15b, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),
                      color: Colors.red,
                      size: 17.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding:
                          const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 10.0, 15.0, 0.0),
                          child: Text(
                            gridName,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black54,
                              fontSize: 20.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output-

```
I/flutter ( 4708): 1  
I/flutter ( 4708): add on pressed  
I/flutter ( 4708): 2  
I/flutter ( 4708): add on pressed  
I/flutter ( 4708): 3  
I/flutter ( 4708): add on pressed 
I/flutter ( 4708): 2  
I/flutter ( 4708): minus on pressed 
I/flutter ( 4708): 1 
I/flutter ( 4708): minus on pressed 
I/flutter ( 4708): 0 
I/flutter ( 4708): minus on pressed
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. I am not going to increment only 'thoub', I will increment each variable like 'shirt, longPants... and so on' when the +/- pressed separately. so because of that, I used a counter in the parameter to send each variable when I call it, but this is not working with me. Really Thank you.

Comment: Hope above code will help you and you can manage dynamic list items  by ArrayList or List<>